# OCR solution for PHP/Python

Tags: php, python, ocr

I'm looking for an OCR Library that could read english text and numbers for PHP or Python 
I don't learning a new programming language just for using an OCR, 
however, if I see that there isn't any other option,  I guess it would be possible
(please nothing .Net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:  http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/

It wraps this engine:  http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Answer (score 0):

To install `tesseract-ocr` for `ubuntu` :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

To us it the, you can use the command-line or use [my own OCR script](http://www.sputnick-area.net/scripts/OCR)